# Many to Many tables ordering using sequelize ORM

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a many to many relationship between User and Branch

```
return Branch.findAll({
        where: {
            void: false,
            active: true,
        },
        include : {
            model: User,
            as: "user",
            where: {
                active: true,
                void: false,
            },
            required: false,
        },
        order: [
            1st order ==> order by branch name
            2nd order ==> order by user name

        ],
    })
```

How can i write a query for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use multiple order columns in sequelize like:

```
order: [
   ['branch_name', 'ASC'], // order by ASCENDING by branch name column
   ['user.name', 'ASC'] // order by ASCENDING by user name column
]
```

Hope this help.

Comment: This gives an error

 `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the answer through this query

```
return Branch.findAll({
  where: {
    void: false,
    active: true,
  },
  include: {
    model: User,
    as: "user",
    where: {
      active: true,
      void: false,
    },
    required: false,
  },
  order: [
    ['branch_name', 'ASC'],
    [{model:User,as:"user"},'name','ASC']
  ],
})
```

Link : [Sequelize documentation](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/eager-loading/)